# Position images with different dimensions centered?

Tags: html, css, image

I have multiple images with different images which I need to display within a overview grid. The images do have totally different dimensions and ratios and the wrapper for these images is always the same height and width.

I'd like to position the images always within the center of the wrapper but that doesn't work.

I use that for the image

```
.content_page .slide_content .product img {
    /* max-height: 100%; */
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    float: none;
    border: none;
}
```

and for the wrapper that one

```
.content_page .slide_content .product {
    width: 27%;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px 3%;
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #121224;
}
```

Very small or wide images now do get aligned at the top of the wrapper as margin:auto doesn't seem to work. What can Id do there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.content_page .slide_content .product {
    width:<some width>;
    height:<some width>;
    position:relative;
}

.content_page .slide_content .product > img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set margin left and right as auto and use vertical align middle

```
.content_page .slide_content .product img {
/* max-height: 100%; */
height: auto;
width: 100%;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
float: none;
border: none;
}
```